# How do I customize this code snippet to work with a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

On a particular website, Posts have a custom taxonomy called "Featured Categories."

Only Posts which belong to the "Featured Category" called "Articles" should be published in the Jetpack-powered Newsletter.

Can I use the following code snippet? Or do I need to modify it somehow to work with "Featured Categories" instead of Categories?

```
function jetpackme_exclude_all_posts_subscriptions_except( $categories ) {
$categories = array( 'articles');
return $categories;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_subscriptions_exclude_all_categories_except', 'jetpackme_exclude_all_posts_subscriptions_except' );
```

The source of the code snippet above is https://jetpack.com/blog/hook-month-control-subscriptions/